# Reverse enter and exit animation for RTL layout - Android Navigation Component

Tags: android, xml, animation, navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using the Android Navigation Architecture Component for navigation between fragments. I've set enter and exit animation for one of the fragment destinations. Animation works correctly and the same for both Left-to-Right and Right-to-Left layouts. I need this animation should consider opposite edges for RTL layout, i.e. what `start` and `end` properties do instead of `left` and `right`. What is the simplest way to achieve the same?

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_fragment"
    android:name="com.example.SignInFragment">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_sign_up"
        app:destination="@id/sign_up_fragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"/>

</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/sign_up_fragment"
    android:name="com.example.SignUpFragment"/>
```

anim/slide_out_left

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p" />
</set>
```

anim/slide_in_right

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0" />
</set>
```

Comment: are you using dataBinding in your app?

Comment: Yes. Though this animation should work independently. @Priyankagb

Comment: I think there is no straight forward way at least none that i know . So you probably have to create a separate file to reverse it and use it as per Locale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same like you do for different density versions of drawables, you can have RTL version of your `anim` resources in `anim-ldrtl` with the same `anim` resource names but exchange the behavior.

For instance `slide_out_left.xml` in `res\anim-ldrtl\` will contain the anim of `slide_out_right.xml` and so on.

You can create  `anim-ldrtl` directory under `res` or you can use Android studio for that:

Right-Click on `res\anim` -> New -> Animation Resource File

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

using data binding you can do this

```
<layout>
    <data>
      <variable
            name="isRTL"
            type="Boolean" />
    </data>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.SignInFragment">
    
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_sign_up"
            app:destination="@id/sign_up_fragment"
            app:enterAnim="@{isRTL ? @anim/slide_in_right : @anim/slide_out_left}"
            app:exitAnim="@{isRTL ? @anim/slide_out_left : @anim/slide_in_right}"/>
    
    </fragment>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This solution (conditional statement) seems to work if there is a layout file. I've `navigation` (navGraph) and I guess the only supported root tag is `navigation`, and `layout` and `data` tags are allowed in this file.